# How to remove white spaces around the button in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple `HTML` button, the button works fine. There is some blank/white space around it. How can I get rid of it? My question might sound silly, but for a beginner like me, I have no idea how to get rid of it.

Thank you.

You can see the white spaces, which I was talking about, in the following screenshot.

[image]

Following is the code I have for buttons.

```html
<p>
  <a class="button" href="https://facebook.com/">
    <button style="background-color:#3b5998; border:none; color:white; border-radius: 3px;">Facebook</button>&nbsp;</a>
  <a class="button" href="https://wa.me/1234567898">
    <button style="background-color:green; border:none; color:white; border-radius: 3px;">WhatsApp</button>
  </a>
</p>

<p>
  <a href="tel:01234567890">
    <input type="image" align="right" src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/hone-icon-866-986-8942-book-online-phone-icon-png-blue-115633551488jsnijarwa.png" name="submit" width="70" height="70" alt="Call Us" value="">
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: First of all, `<a>` should not contain any other Action Elements (like `<button>`). 
 Secondly, stop using inline `style` attributes. Use a proper CSS file or a `<style>` tag.  Also, don't use `&nbsp;`, use styles instead - if you want to add spacings like `margin`s

Comment: Start by fixing the errors that a validator would highlight: https://validator.nu/

Comment: "Note: I cannot use css, I can only use html." — There's a lot of CSS in that code for someone who can't use it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tested your code in opera, it's working as expected here.
[https://i.imgur.com/HAl4Xka.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5KCC.png)

EDIT: I've fixed the code following the suggestions made in your first post.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .fb-button, .wa-button {
            border:none; 
            color:white;
            border-radius: 3px;
            padding: 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .fb-button {
            background-color:#3b5998;
        }

        .wa-button {
            background-color:green;
        }

        .container {
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 50%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        form {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container">
        <a class="fb-button" href="https://facebook.com/">Facebook</a>
        <a class="wa-button" href="https://wa.me/1234567898">WhatsApp</a>

        <form action="tel:01234567890" method="GET">
            <input type="image" src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/hone-icon-866-986-8942-book-online-phone-icon-png-blue-115633551488jsnijarwa.png" width="70" height="70" alt="Call Us">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked for both `Facebook` and `WhatsApp` buttons after changing the code a bit. I added `style="border:none; color:white;"` to button also. Without it, there had been a border and the font colour was changed to white. As for the call/round button, I still have the white space around it. The image is PNG as I can see in the link. Can you check what is the issue?

Comment: Yes, it worked. I wonder why people are voting down my question and your answer even though it worked. Can you make the changes in your answer so that I can accept it as the answer?

Comment: Yes, there you go.

Answer (score -1):

- `<a>` should not contain any other Action Elements (like `<button>`).
- Stop using the inline `style` attributes. Use a proper CSS file or a `<style>` tag.
- Don't use `&nbsp;`, use styles instead - if you want to add spacings like margins
- Use `flex` to ease the positioning of your elements

```css
.buttons-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.color-fb {
  background-color: #3b5998;
}

.color-wa {
  background-color: #00aa45;
}

.img-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3rem;
}

/* Utility classes */

.u-left-auto {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons-group">
  <a class="button color-fb" href="https://facebook.com/">Facebook</a>
  <a class="button color-wa" href="https://wa.me/1234567898">WhatsApp</a>
  <a class="button u-left-auto" href="tel:01234567890">
    <img class="img-icon" src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/hone-icon-866-986-8942-book-online-phone-icon-png-blue-115633551488jsnijarwa.png" alt="Call Us">
  </a>
</div>
```